# What's the difference between a "classic" and "module" Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm learning about the JavaScript **Web Worker** APIs, using the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation as a primary source. [The documentation suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) that the constructor for a new Worker accepts a `type` parameter. This `type` parameter can accept values of either `classic` or `module`, according to the same document.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't describe the difference between `classic` and `module`. When would I want to use `classic` vs. `module` and what behavioral differences are there between the two "types" of Workers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `module` type serves roughly the same purpose as the [`type="module"` attribute does for a script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). It tells the browser the worker script being loaded is an ES6 module (which is necessary meta data to know how to parse and run it, [as this article goes into a bit](http://2ality.com/2017/05/es-module-specifiers.html)).

You would use it if your worker module was an ES6 module (possibly with `import` statements). It also has the bonus of being able to load a worker from a different origin if CORS are enabled, which classic workers cannot (which might be an attractive feature, even if not using `import` statements).

From **[HTML Living Standard - Using a JavaScript module as a worker](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#module-worker-example):**

> All of our examples so far show workers that run classic scripts. Workers can instead be instantiated using module scripts, which have the usual benefits: the ability to use the JavaScript import statement to import other modules; strict mode by default; and top-level declarations not polluting the worker's global scope.
>
> Note that such module-based workers follow different restrictions regarding cross-origin content, compared to classic workers. Unlike classic workers, module workers can be instantiated using a cross-origin script, as long as that script is exposed using the CORS protocol. Additionally, the importScripts() method will automatically fail inside module workers; the JavaScript import statement is generally a better choice.

As of the original post date, you probably wouldn't have used it in production as browser support for ES6 modules was not that great. As of 2020 even though most major browser have ES6 module support for scripts, that does not extend to workers. [Currently only Chrome 80+ has this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Is there any browser that supports this at all, without any meddling?

Comment: @TomášZato not yet https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5761300827209728, but they're somewhat inevitable now that ES modules are rapidly becoming the standard.

Comment: @Keith Actually I eventually successfully tested code that uses it in Google Chrome. Had to enable dev flags of course. But in Firefox, it does not work even with dev flags :(

Comment: @TomášZato yeah, it's behind flags thanks to a couple of bugs, linked to that status. You can use bundling tools (Rollup, WebPack, etc) to bundle the worker JS, but you can't work around the CORS thing. Chrome don't always get these sorts of things right (see HTML Imports) but there have been several competing and quirky/hacky module loaders and now ES Modules are rapidly becoming the standard. I'd be very surprised if they go with something else for workers, or if they dropped workers.

Comment: Yeah, I also hope they will get this right. I§m really tired of alternating module loaders. But still Node.JS has a long way to go for actual useable support.

Comment: It is now supported in Chrome 80

Comment: Saying "most major browsers" when it's just Blink is a bit of a stretch...

Comment: @Kaiido Do you have a source for that? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility) and [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module) says ES6 modules are supported in all major browsers except for IE (which isn't getting new features).

Comment: So this sentence is about ES6 modules or about module Workers? The former indeed is now well supported, the later is still Blink only.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess I assumed their availability would be linked. I'm not having any luck finding info on Workers specifically.

Comment: After the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#Browser_compatibility) there is a note.